# "deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead"

Tags: command-line

I've got a problem while I'm trying to install:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

the message is:

```
deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead
```

I'm trying to deploy an App on firebase, after this message I can't complete the steps that mentioned in firebase site. 
any help ?!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The node-uuid module is deprecated, you need to install uuid module.

```
npm install -g uuid
```

Answer (score 1):

**node-uuid** is now deprecated. Run the following commands:

```
npm uninstall --save node-uuid
npm install --save uuid
```